# Running multiple ECS services in single EC2 instance using Elastic beanstalk

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, microservices, amazon-ecs

I have created 10 microservice dockers for web services and pushed the created images to ECS and deployed them using elastic beanstalk. Placed all the dockers in single Task definition and created a service for application-level auto-scaling. It created another task by duplicate it while auto-scaling.

I want to apply the auto scaling only for dockers, not for the task. If one docker affected by CPU or memory load, auto-scaling should create the copy of the particular docker only(not the whole task). How can I achieve this in ECS using Elastic Beanstalk? Is it possible to create 10 services and each contains single task and single docker container to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If one docker affected by CPU or memory load, auto-scaling should create the copy of the particular docker only(not the whole task). How can I achieve this in ECS using Elastic Beanstalk?

ECS can only scale whole task definitions. This is defined at the ECS service level using [service auto scaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html). Unfortunately I can't speak to how Elastic Beanstalk handles this, as I don't use it for container management.

> Is it possible to create 10 services and each contains single task and single docker container to resolve this problem?

In short, yes, this is how you would solve your problem. Those 10 services can still coexist on as many or as few cluster instances as you like.